# C++ gcc does associative-math flag disable float NAN values?

Tags: c++, gcc, optimization, floating-point, fast-math

I'm working with statistic functions with a lot of float data. I want it to run faster but `Ofast` disable NAN (`fno-finite-math-only` flag), which is not allowed in my case.

In this case, is it safe to turn on only `associative-math` ? I think this flag allows things like vectorized sum of vector array, even if the array contains NAN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html):

> NOTE: re-ordering may change the sign of zero as well as ignore NaNs

So if you want correct handling of NaNs, you should not use `-fassociative-math`.